# Как грамотно и оптимизировано сделать пагинацию?

Tags: php

Имею такой код, живой пример сайта: https://hr-tape.ru/

```
  switch ($_GET['e']) {
    default:
          $title = $title->posts;
          $query_count = 'SELECT count(*) FROM `posts`';
          $query = 'SELECT * FROM `posts` ';
          $query .= 'ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT ';
          if (is_numeric($_GET['offset'])) {
              $query .= '?,';
              $array = array();
              array_push($array, $_GET['offset']);
          }
          $query .= 5;
          $response = sendQuery($query,$array)->fetchAll();
          $count = sendQuery($query_count, null)->fetchColumn();
          if (!empty($response)) {
              foreach ($response as $post) {
                  $posts.= str_replace(
                      array('$ID$','$TITLE$','$DESC$','$VIEWS$','$COMMENTS$','$DATE$'),
                      array($post['id'],$post['title'],htmlspecialchars_decode($post['desc']),getViewsCount(1, $post['id']).' '.trueWord(getViewsCount(1, $post['id']), 'просмотр', 'просмотра', 'просмотров'),getCommentsCount($post['id']).' '.trueWord(getCommentsCount($post['id']), 'комментарий', 'комментария', 'комментариев'),timeTransform($post['date'])),
                      getTpl('posts_row'));
              }
              if (isset($_GET['scroll'])) exit ($posts);
              else $content = str_replace(array('$POSTS$','$COUNT$'),array($posts,$count),getTpl('posts'));
          }
          else if (!isset($_GET['scroll'])) {
            showException('posts_not_found');
          }
      break;
      case 'post':
          if (is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
              $query = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1';
...
```

За SQL запросы и прочую мелочевку не ругайте, сайт пока на живом дебаге :)

Суть в том что сначала я хотел сделать прогрузку публикаций по скроллу вниз, но потом понял что для SEO это не очень хорошо, и решил сделать по стандартному, но пока не знаю как, а информации в интернете очень много и кода там еще больше.

В общем прошу от вас простой пример надежной пагинации, т.е нужно узнать:

- текущую страницу и пометить ее как неактивную
- количество страниц (на каждой странице по 5 публикаций)

Ну и соотвественно вывести их по допустим такому шаблону:

```
<div pages>
<a href="/?posts&page=1" class="btn page disabled">1</a>
<a href="/?posts&page=2" class="btn page">2</a>
<a href="/?posts&page=3" class="btn page">3</a>
<a href="/?posts&page=4" class="btn page">4</a>
<a href="/?posts&page=5" class="btn page">5</a>
</div>
```

От вас необязательно сам код, я не понимаю пока еще самой теории, и чтобы не делать костылей, обращаюсь за пояснениями к вам.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вам посоветовал использовать [bootstrap пагинацию](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/pagination/) или [semantic UI пагинацию](https://react.semantic-ui.com/addons/pagination#types-pagination)

Answer (score -1):

Быстрее было разобраться самому, вот ответ:

```
switch ($_GET['e']) {
    default:
          $title = $title->posts;
          $count = sendQuery('SELECT count(*) FROM `posts`', null)->fetchColumn();
          if ($_GET['page'] > 1) {
          $page = $_GET['page'];
          $offset = ($page - 1) * 10;
          $limit = 10;
          $response = sendQuery('SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT '.$offset.', '.$limit, null)->fetchAll();
        }
        else {
          $page = 1;
          $response = sendQuery('SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10',null)->fetchAll();
        }
          if (!empty($response)) {
              foreach ($response as $post) {
                  $posts.= str_replace(
                      array('$ID$','$TITLE$','$DESC$','$VIEWS$','$COMMENTS$','$DATE$'),
                      array($post['id'],$post['title'],htmlspecialchars_decode($post['desc']),getViewsCount(1, $post['id']).' '.trueWord(getViewsCount(1, $post['id']), 'просмотр', 'просмотра', 'просмотров'),getCommentsCount($post['id']).' '.trueWord(getCommentsCount($post['id']), 'комментарий', 'комментария', 'комментариев'),timeTransform($post['date'])),
                      getTpl('posts_row'));
              }
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $count / 10; $i++) {
                  if($i == $page) {
                    $pages .= str_replace('$NUMBER$',$i,getTpl('page_current'));
                  } else {
                    $pages .= str_replace('$NUMBER$',$i,getTpl('page'));
                  }
                }
                $content = str_replace(array('$POSTS$','$COUNT$','$PAGES$'),array($posts,$count,$pages),getTpl('posts'));
              } else  {
            showException('posts_not_found');
          }
      break;
}
```